Debugging NestJS project in VS Code using docker - breakpoint misalignment after changes
Problem description
I have a NestJS project in docker. I have successfully set up debugging in VS Code. The issue is that as I adjust the code, the breakpoints I set in different places in code become misaligned. It seems to me as if source maps were not updated when adjusting the code.
After restarting the script and re-attaching debugger, everything is aligned again.
See this example:

Here I have set breakpoint on line 63.
After adding few lines, the original line 63 is now line 79. If I try to set first breakpoint on new code on line 70, it is set in the middle of the word console.
When I want to set breakpoint on the original code console.log("abc") which is now on line 79, the breakpoint is set on line 81 instead.

If there are many changes (added/deleted lines of code) the breakpoints on the new lines are not even hit.
Question
Any idea what am I doing wrong? Any suggestions that could help solve this problem?
Configuration:
Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

ADD nest-cli.json .
ADD tsconfig.json .
ADD tsconfig.build.json .
ADD ./.vscode/launch.json ./.vscode/


EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9229

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:debug"]


launch.json
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [      
        {
          "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
          "type": "node",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9229,
          "address": "localhost",
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "remoteRoot": "/app",
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "restart": true
        }
    ]
}

package.json
{
    "scripts": {
    "docker-dev": "nest build && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug=0.0.0.0 --watch",
  },

docker-dev script is used to run project in debug mode.
tsconfig.json (in case it is needed for resolving the issue)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}

tsconfig.build.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}

Some resources that did not help
I have spent quite some time looking for solution but none worked. Usually, the project had other issues or different configurations. Here are just few resources:
Debugger doesn't properly catch execution in TypeScript
Debugging nest.js application with vscode
Node vs-code debugger is showing unbound breakpoint in Docker
